# Firebase data not loading on apk versions both debug/release, but loads when running through android studio

Tags: android, mobile, firebase

app runs perfectly fine when running through android studio, all the firebase data loads correctly, but when i generate apk and install it via phone, firebase data doesn't load...what is missing in my firebase setup, already setup SHA-1 fingerprint for release/debug....

Comment: is there any error log? perhaps it's about permission issue?

Comment: when running from android studio there is no error log, whereas running app from apk doesn't fetch images on homescreen but content on inner page is loading..

Comment: can't understand the problem..its wierd

Comment: Did you solved this issue?